# Working on a JavaScript Tic Tac Toe game: Is there a way to correspond my id tagged elements into an array? Need it for the Victory Condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, tic-tac-toe

I working on a Tic Tac Toe game that I can add for my GitHub. I was able to implement DOM elements into my game successfully, and can successfully add my X's and O's onto my board using the event.target.classList.add(). I have set my DOM X and O elements to work as a Boolean with the X's being set to 'true' and O's being set to 'false'. However as of now, I only have the board placement component done, I need to be able to set my victory conditions.

The 'cells' of my game board are all given the id tag 'cell-#' in accordance to their number on the board. They appear as the following:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

Where
#cell-1 top most left
#cell-6 middle right etc.

I want to be able to match them with their corresponding values on the array for my JavaScript file.

[0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8]

Where
#cell-1 = 0
#cell-2 = 1 etc.

I'm hoping that I will then be able to set my victory conditions for my board more easily.
So an X on spaces 1, 5, and 9 (or [0,4,8]) is a win for player X.

I'd really appreciate some help

*note, it says on const gameState that players are 'x' and 'o', I'm thinking of turning it into 'true' and 'false'. Not sure how to set that one up.

[code for my html as you can see I've given all my cells the id tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeD5k.png)
[what it looks like on liveserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7J9s.png)
[my code for JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWtOi.png)

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to synchronize my html elements synchronize with an array in JavaScript.

Comment: Don't post images of your code. Please edit your question to include the code in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByClassName` to obtain an array of the cells:

```js
const gameState = {
  ...
  board: document.getElementsByClassName("ticTacToeCell");
  ...
};
```

Then, if you want to check if player X has won for spaces 1, 5, and 9, you could do:

```js
console.log(gameState.board[0].classList.contains("X_BoardPiece") && 
  gameState.board[4].classList.contains("X_BoardPiece") && 
  gameState.board[8].classList.contains("X_BoardPiece"))
```

You can put this logic in a function to make the code more concise:

```js
function checkWin(player, cells) {
  return cells.every(cell => gameState.board[cell].classList.contains(`${player}_BoardPiece`));
}

console.log(checkWin("X", [0, 4, 8]));
```